# Coloring Country while showing mappoint for cities in world map using highmaps

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am working with highmaps and have plotted the cities with map-points using lat-long for the same.

Now , I want to color  particular countries say India and USA .

Is there any way to achieve the same ?

Below is my js file for plotting world map with citis mappoints with help of lat/lon

```
// Initiate the chart

$.getJSON("/MyProject/HighChartPhp/getMapData.php", function (data) {

    // Correct UK to GB in data
    $.each(data, function () {
        if (this.code === 'UK') {
            this.code = 'GB';
        }
    });

    //console.log(data);

    var final_array = [];

    for(var i in data[0].data)
    {
        var map_data = {
            name: data[0].name[i],
            lat: data[0].lat[i],
            lon: data[0].lon[i],
            z: data[0].data[i],
            val: data[0].loc[i],
            color: data[0].color[i]
        }

        //console.log(map_data);

        final_array[i] = map_data;
    }

    console.log(final_array);

    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            map: 'custom/world'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Word Wide Data Usage'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },

        tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.val}</b><br/>{point.z}'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        series: [{
        // Use the gb-all map with no data as a basemap
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        name: 'Basemap',
        borderColor: 'green',
        nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3)',
        showInLegend: true
    }, {
        // Specify points using lat/lon
        type: 'mappoint',
        name: 'Cities',
        //color: 'blue',
        data: final_array
    }]

    });

});
```

How can I color India and US in the map ?

Tried the below , but still it is not working . 
// Initiate the chart

```
$.getJSON("/MyProject/HighChartPhp/getMapData.php", function (data) {

    // Correct UK to GB in data
    $.each(data, function () {
        if (this.code === 'UK') {
            this.code = 'GB';
        }
    });

    data.forEach(function(point, index) {
        console.log("country="+point.country);
    if (point.country === 'India' || point.country === 'United States') {
      point.color = 'green';
    }
  });

    //console.log(data);

    var final_array = [];

    for(var i in data[0].data)
    {
        var map_data = {
            name: data[0].name[i],
            lat: data[0].lat[i],
            lon: data[0].lon[i],
            z: data[0].data[i],
            val: data[0].loc[i],
            color: data[0].color[i],
            country:data[0].country[i]
        }

        //console.log(map_data);

        final_array[i] = map_data;
    }

    console.log(final_array);

    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            map: 'custom/world'
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Word Wide outsource Vendor Usage'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },

         colorAxis: {
      min: 1,
      max: 1000,
      type: 'logarithmic'
        },

        tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.val}</b><br/>{point.z}'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        series: [{
        // Use the gb-all map with no data as a basemap
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        name: 'Basemap',
        borderColor: 'green',
        nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3)',

        showInLegend: true
    }, {
        // Specify points using lat/lon
        type: 'mappoint',
        name: 'Cities',
        //color: 'blue',
        data: final_array
    }]

    });

});
```

Below is json data :

```
"name": [
"Ahemdabad",
"Atlanta",
"Bangalore",
"Bangkok",
"Buenos Aires",
"Chennai",
"Chicago",
"Cochin",
"Colombo",
"Dallas",
"Delhi",
"Hyderabad",
"Irvine",
"Irvine Dallas",
"Johannesburg",
"Kolkata",
"Kuala Lumpur",
"Lima",
"Los Angeles",
"Miami",
"Moscow",
"Mumbai",
"New Jersey",
"New York",
"Niagra",
"Philadelphia",
"Rio",
"Riyadh",
"Seattle",
"Syracuse",
"Washington Baltimore"
],
"loc": [
"Ahemdabad:India",
"Atlanta:USA",
"Bangalore:India",
"Bangkok:Thailand",
"Buenos Aires:Argentina",
"Chennai:India",
"Chicago:USA",
"Cochin:India",
"Colombo:Sri Lanka",
"Dallas:USA",
"Delhi:India",
"Hyderabad:India",
"Irvine:USA",
"Irvine Dallas:USA",
"Johannesburg:South Africa",
"Kolkata:India",
"Kuala Lumpur:Malaysia",
"Lima:Peru",
"Los Angeles:USA",
"Miami:USA",
"Moscow:Russia",
"Mumbai:India",
"New Jersey:USA",
"New York:USA",
"Niagra:USA",
"Philadelphia:USA",
"Rio:Brazil",
"Riyadh:Saudi Arabia",
"Seattle:USA",
"Syracuse:USA",
"Washington Baltimore:USA"
],
"color": [
"#FFC300",
"#EC32BF",
"#FFC300",
"#EC32BF",
"#49EC32",
"#FFC300",
"#EC3246",
"#FFC300",
"#EC32BF",
"#EC3246",
"#EC32BF",
"#FFC300",
"#EC32BF",
"#16F7EC  ",
"#EC32BF",
"#FFC300",
"#EC32BF",
"#FFC300",
"#581845",
"#EC32BF",
"#EC32BF",
"#FFC300",
"#EC32BF",
"#EC32BF",
"#3A32EC",
"#EC32BF",
"#49EC32",
"#EC32BF",
"#EC32BF",
"#EC32BF",
"#EC32BF"
],
"lat": [
23.022505,
33.748995,
12.971599,
13.756331,
-34.603684,
13.08268,
41.878114,
9.931233,
6.927079,
32.776664,
28.704059,
17.385044,
33.684567,
33.684567,
-26.204103,
22.572646,
3.139003,
-12.046373,
34.052234,
25.76168,
55.755826,
19.075984,
40.058324,
40.712784,
43.082816,
39.952584,
-22.906847,
24.713552,
47.606209,
43.048122,
39.177404
],
"lon": [
72.571362,
-84.387982,
77.594563,
100.501765,
-58.381559,
80.270718,
-87.629798,
76.267304,
79.861243,
-96.796988,
77.10249,
78.486671,
-117.826505,
-117.826505,
28.047305,
88.363895,
101.686855,
-77.042754,
-118.243685,
-80.19179,
37.6173,
72.877656,
-74.405661,
-74.005941,
-79.074163,
-75.165222,
-43.172896,
46.675296,
-122.332071,
-76.147424,
-76.668392
],
"country": [
"India",
"USA",
"India",
"Thailand",
"Argentina",
"India",
"USA",
"India",
"Sri Lanka",
"USA",
"India",
"India",
"USA",
"USA",
"South Africa",
"India",
"Malaysia",
"Peru",
"USA",
"USA",
"Russia",
"India",
"USA",
"USA",
"USA",
"USA",
"Brazil",
"Saudi Arabia",
"USA",
"USA",
"USA"
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add property to specific points from the data, before joining with `mapData`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series%3Cmappoint%3E.data.color

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0Lcwn3pj/

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working , updated the same in the question , can you please help to check if i missed something .

Comment: I am looking to color "us with red" and "russia with blue" in the following fiddle .
http://jsfiddle.net/dnbtkmyz/